# prevent a package from rebuilding when using yarn install or add

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

I'm using bootstrap for a react project along with Yarn as package manager.
I stripped down the bootstrap package to only keep the modal component (and thus avoid unnecessary weight). 
The issue is that whenever I'm adding a package in my project, it seems like the bootstrap package is rebuilt, adding back all the components I initially removed.
Is there a way to prevent the bootstrap package from rebuilding when even i'm doing a `yarn install` or a `yarn add` ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/#importing-components) you can find info about how to import individual components:

> You should import individual components like: react-bootstrap/Button
> rather than the entire library. Doing so pulls in only the specific
> components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of
> code you end up sending to the client.

```
// Import single component
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

// or less ideally (imports the entire library)
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Other way would be forking the project to your personal repository and creating a version for your specific needs. But later would be harder to upgrade.

Comment: Even though you're just importing the Button component in your example, the whole bootstrap library is still added to my repo when doing 'yarn add react-bootstrap', isn't it ?  My point was to avoid increasing my repo size with unused stuff

Comment: Yes, the entire library will be installed. But your final build will include only the used components.
If your point is saving space in your local machine, then creating a fork is the best option. But you will be saving around 8 MB.